# show button in repeated list only if index is more than 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeated list how do I show a button within the list only if $index is more than 1 ?

plunkr to get started: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/beDxlgU8kDVIhI6DGAYB?p=preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf) is only in available in angular 1.1.5 and later. Either upgrade the Angular version, or use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) instead:

```
<p data-ng-show="$index > 1">
  <a href="#">This button will only show when index is more than 1</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Or use AngularUI, which has `ui-if` and a lot of other goodies.